# How to automatically bind template types in Enterprise Architect when a class is realizing a generic interface

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I have defined a generic interface using Enterprise Architect (see figure below).
[image]

I would now like to specify the following realization:

```
class AircraftsTypesRepository implements Repository<AircraftTypes, Integer>
```

Is there a way for EA to automatically bind types and method signatures to the generic types I specified in the base interface. In other words, I would like to show in the diagram that for the `AircraftTypesRepository` class, `T` and `K` and bound to `T=AircraftTypes`, and `K=Integer`. I would also like to see this reflected in the interface methods

Comment: Good question, but one I can't answer. AFAIK it's not possible (except you use notes or the like).

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this and (as there's no native support) would suggest to script that. There are plenty of ways, so I'd take a KISS one. The `Realize` relation could be adorned with tagged values named *Bind`<val>`* or so where *`<val>`* is the name of a template parameter (in your example T or K). These TVs should then be defined as RefGUID which allows them to link to an EA element. Creating these TVs should be one script which looks into the templated class. You find the template definition in the table `t_xref` with

```
SELECT description FROM t_xref 
WHERE client = `<GUID of element>` AND type = `elment property`
```

This will contain something like

> @ELEMENT;GUID={5EC3D8DF-BC37-4529-8F36-0D9BA363955D};Name=E;Type=ClassifierTemplateParameter;Pos=0;@ENDELEMENT;;

(I created an example with just `T` but you will decode it easily, I guess.)

Now that you have the tagged value(s) set in the Realize you can run a second script to synch the definition ("just" look for textually identical types). Later you could alter the TVs and re-synch again (AFAIK there's not hook for TVs being altered so that needs to be triggered manually).

This is not a complete solution but just a suggestion which leaves open quite some field for experimentation (and failure).